# Android Display new Class without new Intent

Tags: android, class, android-intent

I have a AsyncTask which connects to a database and returns an JSONArray. The data is displayed in a ListView. Now if I click a ListItem I start a new Intent with the data from the JSONObject

```
Intent it = new Intent(DisplaySearchResults.this, Display.class);
try
{
   it.putExtra("ID", jArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("ID").toString());
   it.putExtra("TITLE", jArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("TITLE").toString());
   it.putExtra("STRING", jArray.getJSONObject(position).getDouble("STRING"));
   it.putExtra("SOME TEXT", jArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("SOME TEXT").toString())
} catch (JSONException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
startActivity(it);
```

Now is it possible to start the display class with something like

```
Display d = new Display(jsonArray);
```

Comment: JSONArray is basically a String so you can put the whole JSON Object as an extra.

Comment: thanks - at least it's much easier that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do that.

Why ?

`Display` is an `Activity` and in Android the Activity lifecycle is managed by the Android framework. It means that Android framework decide when creating a new instance of any Activity.

The contract is :

- when a new instance of an Activity is created : the Android framework will call the `onCreate` method to give you the opportunity the initialize the new Activity.
- you are not allowed to instantiate a new Activity yourself (i.e. by calling `new`)
- you can ask the Android framework to create a new instance of any Activity by using an Intent, and Android framework will do it for you asynchronously.

---

For completeness, let me add the following :

- under some circumstances, for instance "screen rotation", the Android framework may decide to destroy and recreate an Activity. To do that : the framework will reuse the Intent that was used initially to create the Activity.
- depending on the Intent flags, Activity launch-mode and if an instance of the target Activity already exists: the framework may decide to NOT create a new instance of the target Activity, but instead it will bring back to front the *already existing instance* of the target Activity.